# Communicate from ViewModel to View in Xamarin MVVM Cross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

We are using Xamarin traditional approach & MVVM Cross.

We want to fire a method which is in the view from ViewModel. What is the best way to achieve it? Is it by IMvxInteraction or MessageCenter?

In another case, we want to fire a method in ViewModel from View. What is the best way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

```
ViewModel 
{
   func method1()
  {
     // Trigger a method in iOS View. Which is method2  

  }
}

iOSView
{
  func method2()
 {

     // Trigger a method in ViewModel. Which is method1  

 }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a method example, that do you want to fire? And please add some ViewModel code.

Comment: For `View to View Model` use `MvxCommand`. For `ViewModel to View` use `MvxInteraction`

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your view to a Command in your ViewModel. See how to use `ICommand` in https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding.

You may look at Method Binding as well https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/methodbinding.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. We want to fire a method in ViewModel from a method in View (Not by the UI) & vice versa.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added the code. Can you please look into it and do needful.

Comment: )) it looks like there is nothing to present in your view. Give me some real code please. So I will understand what do you mean. At least I need a caller of the method in your view.

Comment: Now It looks like a design problem.